# How to save Facebook access token from OAuth alert dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, oauth

I have an OAuth facebook login service in a phonegap app and when executed it returns the access token in an alert dialog.

Is there a way I can save this token in localstorage for use with facebook API?

After OAuth has initialized the following code is on button click and opens the Facebook popup. User logs in and the access token is printed

```
OAuth.popup('facebook', function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        alert(error); // do something with error
        return;
    }
    result.get('/me').done(function(data) {
        alert("User name: " + data.name + ". User email: " + data.email);
        facebook_service.execute({data:{
             "user_id":data.id, "access_token":result.access_token
        }});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just can use html5 localstorage object adding this at your result callback:

```
localstorage.setItem("myToken", result.access_token);
```